# Why is RWTime using a different default timezone than the one the date command uses?

Tags: linux, bash, date, time, rogue-wave

I normally get the same time but there is a host on which, when I run the following simple program:

```
int main()
{
    RWTime now;
    std::cout << now.asString() << "," << RWZone::local().timeZoneName() << std::endl;
}
```

I get output like this:

```
$> date && ./simple_program
Thu Jun 12 03:16:34 EST 2014
06/12/2014 04:16:34,EST
```

If the timezone is the same, how can they be producing different results? The date command is right, but the RWTime from simple program is one hour ahead of reality.

Answer (score 0):

It would appear that your locale is using `EST`, not `EDT`, so the `date` program is returning a time an hour earlier than the actual time. `RWZONE.local()` appears to use daylight saving time, but reports the name of the time zone as `EST`, not `EDT`.

Comment: RWTime is one hour ahead, the real time is the one suggested by the date bash command. How does one fix locale here?

Comment: What does `/etc/localtime` point to? I would expect `date` to be reporting the timezone as `EDT` this time of year.

Comment: Hm. That's quite different from what I was expecting (`EST` is (North American) Eastern Standard Time, not Australian Eastern Standard Time).

Comment: Yes the host is in australia...but what throws me off is why the date command and RWTime locale are one hour apart

Comment: I'd be willing to bet that `RWZone.isDaylight()` returns true, indicating that despite the labels, the two programs are using different time zones. `date` is using true Eastern Standard Time (no daylight saving), and `RWZone` is using Eastern Daylight Saving (EDT), accounting for the later reported time, but calling it EST.

Comment: It does return true - why would it think this? How can it be corrected?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55458/discussion-between-chepner-and-palace-chan).